# Trying to get Cassandra to listen on two interfaces at the same time

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra documentation states that you have to specify a single address to listen on, but I would imagine that it is fairly common to need to bind to two interfaces, one internal and one external for other nodes to connect to.

The documentation states that using 0.0.0.0 is always wrong, but i'm wondering how people get around this for cloud environments, where they wish to use the high speed interconnection of the private network for local nodes, and then peer them using a public interface.

Here is the excerpt from the configuration file:

```
# Address or interface to bind to and tell other Cassandra nodes to connect to.
# You _must_ change this if you want multiple nodes to be able to communicate!
#
# Set listen_address OR listen_interface, not both. Interfaces must correspond
# to a single address, IP aliasing is not supported.
#
# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing _if_ the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be).
#
# Setting listen_address to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.
#
# If you choose to specify the interface by name and the interface has an ipv4 and an ipv6 address
# you can specify which should be chosen using listen_interface_prefer_ipv6. If false the first ipv4
# address will be used. If true the first ipv6 address will be used. Defaults to false preferring
# ipv4. If there is only one address it will be selected regardless of ipv4/ipv6.
listen_address: 0.0.0.0
# listen_interface: eth0
# listen_interface_prefer_ipv6: false
```